# Oracle CRM OnDemand custom web applet - add User object variables to URL

Tags: oracle, applet, integration

I have a custom web applet that I am adding to the Lead object tab of my Oracle CRM On Demand app. It is easy to include a variable in the URL via the %%%VARIABLE_NAME%%% convention but that seems to only work with the object itelse (Lead, Service Request, etc) Since the field I want to add is part of a different object (the User) it doesnt seem to be working.

Any help on how to add this would be greatly appreciated.

Here it talks about custom web applets, and under Fields it talks about adding a variable: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14388_01/books/OnDemOLH/index.htm?toc.htm?creatingcwa.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a definitive "not possible" from an oracle web service developer on this issue.

So turns out that in a custom web applet for one object you cannot have custom fields from other objects.

My work-around is to pass the unique userid %%%User id%%% back to my app and work from there.